# Looking for FTP server recommendations for BSD

Tags: ftp, freebsd, sftp, security, bsd

I'm currently deciding on what ftp server we should use for an internal system that we have running FreeBSD 6.2. The requirements that we'll need are the following:

- must be able to handle SSL, as all of our traffic outside our network must be encrypted.
- Easy to set up
- if possible, have plugins for eclipse to make the developers happy. )this one isn't as important as the rest.)
- history of being secure
- a server that is still being maintained

Anyone have any recommendations to offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to all of those bullet points is **SFTP**.

It's already installed, encrypted, secure, maintained and there are Eclipse plugins available.

That doesn't leave many good reasons to use FTP.

Comment: Plus all the configuration can be done in sshd_config with already familiar syntax.

Comment: So selected. Much obliged.

Comment: I'm glad you ditched FTP :)

Answer (score 3):

**vsftpd** - http://vsftpd.beasts.org/ is a really good ftpd. Supports SSL, easy to setup, *very* secure and is still being maintained.

- Latest release: Aug 2009 - vsftpd-2.2.0 released
- It is written by someone who is a vulnerability researcher.

(I dunno about an eclipse plugin but I guess it uses ftp??)

Comment: Gave this one a try and works super. Decided to go with SFTP thought as it also worked and I'm a stickler for not having any more packages on my box then I need.

Answer (score 2):

Proftpd. Apache-style config, and it uses sendfile() so transfers use just about zero cpu.

Better: Don't use FTP at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [pure-ftpd](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd), the code is continuously audited and has always be a very secure and efficient ftp server and you can use SSL/TLS support if you wish it.